# Invoke Method from a Class at Run-tIme in Objective C

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, objective-c-runtime

I want to call the Firebase SubscribeToTopic at runtime in objective C.
And was successful in doing so using the performSelector as implemented below:

```
Class firebase = NSClassFromString(@"FIRMessaging");
SEL selectSubscribeToTopic=NSSelectorFromString(@"subscribeToTopic:");
SEL selectMessaging=NSSelectorFromString(@"messaging");

[[firebase performSelector:selectMessaging] performSelector:selectSubscribeToTopic withObject:topic withObject:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Framework Error while Subscribe");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Framework Subscribed to %@ topic",topic);
    }
}];
```

But the completion block is never executed. Could someone suggest the best possible suggestion to achieve the runtime implementation of Firebase SubscribeToTopic method.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Perhaps use `FIRMessaging`: `[[FIRMessaging messaging] subscribeToTopic:@"test"]` (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessaging.m#L695)

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, but  I was not able to get whether the subscribe was successful or not.

Comment: Try NSSelectorFromString(@"subscribeToTopic:completion:")

Comment: Methods are *always* called at run time.

Comment: @algrid : Thanks a lot ..! it did work and helped me to resolve my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is `subscribeToTopic:`.  That implies that the method only takes one argument; an NSString that describes the topic, I would assume.

So, passing a completion block as a second argument isn't going to do anything.  There is nothing magical about the runtime that'll cause a completion block to execute simply by passing it as an extra argument.

All of this raises a different question;  *Why are you using `performSelector:` at all?*